# Unable to listen for url changes via WebRequest or will-navigate on Electron app

Tags: electron

I'm trying to set up `OAuth authentication` on an Electron app. I want to redirect the user to the `http://localhost:1212/auth/discord?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` url (Electron) after Discord grants the `code`. After that I want to listen for URL changes, grab the `code` and proceed further with the authentication.

I have tried using `onBeforeRequest` of `WebRequest`:

```
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeRequest(filter, function (details, callback) {
  const url = details.url;
  // process the callback url and get any param you need
  console.log(url);
  // don't forget to let the request proceed
  callback({
    cancel: false
  });
});
```

and also the `will-navigate` event:

```
authWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', function (event, newUrl) {
    console.log(newUrl);
    // More complex code to handle tokens goes here
});
```

The problem is that the code detects URL changes only at the startup of the app. That is, `console.log(url)` gives this at the startup:

```
http://localhost:1212/index.html
http://localhost:1212/renderer.dev.js
http://localhost:1212/e227b7535d8985229f67.ttf
http://localhost:1212/561d6473df8929bca8c0.ttf
http://localhost:1212/index.html
```

but when I try going to `http://localhost:1212/auth/discord?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` I get responses like these (not coming from `onBeforeRequest` or `will-navigate`):

```
Rewriting GET /auth/discord?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx to /index.html
Rewriting GET /auth/discord?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx to /index.html
Rewriting GET /auth/discord?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx to /index.html
```

Visiting `http://localhost:1212/index.html` is not detected at all. I'm using `electron-react-boilerplate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Electron tracks such events only inside windows which originate from the main Electron window. That is, it doesn't track events if you just open the localhost app via your browser.

My solution was to create a special HTTP server and bundle it into the app. The server is responsable for accepting the OAuth codes.